# Laravel - Get Data from Table where clause in other table

Tags: laravel, relation

I have this following 2 tables:

Table: Products

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |  fn_id  | created_at  |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |    4    |  SOME TIME  |
|  2 |    5    |  SOME TIME  |
|  3 |    6    |  SOME TIME  |
|  4 |    10   |  SOME TIME  |
|  5 |    10   |  SOME TIME  |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

Table Fn

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |  fn_id  | created_at  |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |    10   |  SOME TIME  |
|  2 |    11   |  SOME TIME  |
|  3 |    12   |  SOME TIME  |
|  4 |    14   |  SOME TIME  |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

And a User Input which is giving me a timestamp ($user_timestamp).

Now I need to get all produtcs, where

```
products.fn_id is 10 
fn.fn_id is 10  
fn.created == $user_timestamp
```

The products model has this relation:

```
public function fn() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\FN', 'fn_id', 'fn_id');
}
```

Now I've tried multiple things like a where query where I want to check if the fn_id on both are "10" and the created_at value of the fn table is equal to $user_timestamp.

However, I wasn't able to do it.

```
$products = Products::with('fn')->where('fn.fn_id', function ($query) use ($user_timestamp) {
            $query->where([['fn_id', 10],['created_at', $user_timestamp]]);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `whereHas` to constrain `Products` based on `fn`.

```
$products = Products::with('fn')->whereHas('fn', function($q) use($user_timestamp){
    $q->where('fn_id', 10)->where('created_at', $user_timestamp);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$id_to_search=10;
$products = Products::with('fn')->where('fbn_id',$id_to_search)->whereHas('fn', function($q) use($user_timestamp,$id_to_search){
    $q->where('fn_id', $id_to_search)->where('created_at', $user_timestamp);
})->get();
```